# Elasticsearch connect to Mongodb

Tags: java, database, mongodb, elasticsearch, search

I have a problem here. There is a website that works with elasticsearch and MongoDB. The problem is this, I have a portaldb and budgetdb database. In fact, this is a portal site in one tab and there is a Budget page on another page. Some elements are being created on the portal itself and these elements need to be transferred via elasticsearch to the Budget page. I have such a question, I can't index some collections from MongoDB on elasticsearch so that elasticsearch saves up-to-date data and passes it to the budget page. To do this, as I understand it, you need to create a new Mongoriver. I deleted all the old indexes and the river, and recreated it. And when running elasticsearch on the server, it writes

> [2024-01-30 17:12:27,938][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.9] - hash[73ddea5] - time[2015-04-06T21:16:46Z]
>
> [2024-01-30 17:12:27,940][ERROR][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Cannot start river subtaxonomyproduct_river. Current status is START_FAILED
>
> [2024-01-30 17:12:27,953][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.9] - hash[73ddea5] - time[2015-04-06T21:16:46Z]
>
> [2024-01-30 17:12:27,953][ERROR][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Cannot start river mongofiles_river. Current status is START_FAILED
>
> [2024-01-30 17:12:27,957][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.9] - hash[73ddea5] - time[2015-04-06T21:16:46Z]
>
> [2024-01-30 17:12:27,957][ERROR][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Cannot start river technopediasoftware_river. Current status is START_FAILED

I'm using mongodb 3.0, elasticsearch 1.4.2, Mongo river 2.0.9. If anything, I can't upgrade.

This is the documentation of the old developers who left.

> Updating the search index:
>
> 1. Raise the archportal and elasticsearch on the local computer
> 2. Make sure that the database is fresh
> 3. Add the software to the required category in the Software reference
> 4. Disable elasticsearch
> 5. Copy the mongotecnhopediaindex and mongoobjectindex folders to the server 192.168.127.87.
> 6. Stop elasticsearch
> 7. Replace the mongotecnhopediaindex and mongoobjectindex folders in /opt/elasticsearch-1.4.2-new/elasticsearch-1.4.2/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/
>    with the new folders that were copied.
> 8. Restart elasticsearch.

I can't run the archportal locally because I didn't write it and former developers don't get in touch. I have access to servers and databases.